# How to access path parameters with postman's test?

Tags: postman

I need to use a path param and it seems works

```
Request1 .../:token/some
```

Now how can I reuse the value provided for `:token` in `Request1` in other request? So that I don't need put same values on every request?

```
Request2 .../:token/other
```

How can I store the value of `:token` in `Request1`'s test codes? I know how to put a value to the environment

```
pm.environment.set("", "");
```

I want to know how to access the value of `:token` path segment.

Comment: [Postman variables](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/variables/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer.

Try to print out the `pm.request.url` which is an array.

Now we can access the path segment with an index.

```
var token = pm.request.url.path[2];
pm.environment.set("token", token);
```